# Hardcode Boolean Query In Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

I'm building an Android application that displays a list of potential matches for a user. The user can click on one to like the user, and I save all of those likes locally.

I can write a query to get the list of matches like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM match WHERE liked = :liked ORDER BY match DESC LIMIT :limit")
fun getMatches(limit: Int = 6, liked: Boolean = true): Flowable<List<Match>>
```

I've learned that this works fine. However, I don't foresee any scenario where I'll ever set `liked` to false, and so I'm curious if there is a way to hardcode my Boolean condition? If I try:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM match WHERE liked = true ORDER BY match DESC LIMIT :limit")
```

I get the following error at compile time:

```
Error:(8, 0) Gradle: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: true)
```

How can I hard code this Boolean in my query string?

I have also tried:

- Wrapping the condition in single quotes

  - `@Query("SELECT * FROM match WHERE liked = 'true' ORDER BY match DESC LIMIT :limit")`

Answer (score 249, accepted):

SQLite does not have a boolean data type. Room maps it to an `INTEGER` column, mapping `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`.

So, I would expect this to work:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM match WHERE liked = 1 ORDER BY match DESC LIMIT :limit")
```

Bear in mind that this behavior is undocumented. However, it shouldn't change — at least not without alarm klaxons sounding — as we'd need to use migrations to deal with any changes.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I definitely think this was missed in the Room documentation.

Comment: @AdamMc331: Particularly after their most recent round of changes, I'd argue that the Room documentation was missed in the Room documentation. :-( But, I'm glad it's working for you!

Comment: Well I got this far with it! :P

Comment: Oh yes, the Room documentation is very sparse... thank you!

Comment: Room database is clearly generating 1 for True and 1 for False buy my queries return null or empty lists. What could the problem be?

Comment: @TheRealChx101: I recommend asking a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem and your symptoms.

Comment: Thanks. So I was able to pull the database file from the device and upon inspection, the are no records inserted in the database. I have a `MediatorLiveData` that I'm using to combine online and offline (cached) items. Somehow my implementation is not saving to the database but going straight to the model view. It's something I can solve but can you recommend a good way when and how to sync the items using `MediatorLiveData` or `Transformations`?

Comment: @TheRealChx101: Once again, I recommend asking a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem and your symptoms.

Comment: so, should i just replace true/false to 0/1 in query only or i have to update table and my code as well??

Comment: @VivekThummar: *Probably* just the query, but it has been a few years since I worked with Room, so I do not know for certain.

Answer (score 34):

CommonWare's approach does work and also answers the OPs question directly; however, I'm not a fan of making such an assumption about the database.  The assumption should be safe, but it may create unexpected work down the road if Room ever decides to change it's boolean implementation.

I'd suggest that the better approach is to not hardcode the boolean 1 or 0 into the query.  If the database is behind a repository, it is still possible for the repository to expose a graceful API.  Personally, I think shielding the larger codebase from the database implementation is a good thing anyways.

Dao Method (copied from OP's question)

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM match WHERE liked = :liked ORDER BY match DESC LIMIT :limit")
fun getMatches(limit: Int = 6, liked: Boolean = true): Flowable<List<Match>>
```

Repository

```
class Repository {
    public Flowable<List<Match>> getLikedMatches() {
        return dao.getMatches(6, true);
    }
}
```

Of course, this is an opinionated option in that it assumes a certain architectural style. However, it does not make assumptions about the internal database.  Even without the repository shielding the database, the call can be made into the database by passing true everywhere - also without making assumptions as to the underlying data.

Comment: If you use different architectural style. you can shield the default value directly in the DAO definition. but you need to define the DAO as an abstract class, not as an interface.
Same definition as above:
`@Query("SELECT * FROM match WHERE liked = :liked ORDER BY match DESC LIMIT :limit")
protected abstract fun getMatches(limit: Int, liked: Boolean): Flowable<List<Match>>`

and the public version

`fun getLikedMatches(limit: Int = 6) = getMatches(limit, true)`

Comment: "if Room ever decides to change it's boolean implementation" - they must not do it because everybody would "damage" existing boolean data when upgrading Room. I have never seen data migration logic for Room library changes.

Comment: "they must not do it" - they can. they might do it slowly, but they absolutely can. It can be dangerous to rely on the underlying implementation of Room.  Because something is exposed is not enough justification to use it - especially when the same end can be gained through documented behavior.

Comment: "they can" but it would be a bug. I can code bugs, too, but surprisingly, nobody likes that.

Comment: a storage library changing its internal implementation is not a bug. I can be terse, too, but surprisingly, nobody likes that.

Answer (score 16):

You don't have to compare boolean column to a value. Just use the column value itself as a boolean expression. You can easily change your query to `SELECT * FROM match WHERE liked ORDER BY match DESC LIMIT :limit`.
If you want to compare to `false` value you can use following expression: `where not liked`.

Comment: you are right .

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM searched_data_table WHERE favourit_history==1 ORDER BY lang_id DESC")
```

Use this query to search data from the table this will give you data in descending order with respect to your key value